# Using API Key to generate chart for external site but showing login screen

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm trying to create a burndown chart on a webapp and using the loginkey example code, but switched loginkey to apikey (code below). My API Key is placed where it says `CorrectAPIKeyHere`, and actual id's for `workspace_id` and `project_id`. I have double checked to make sure it's the correct key. Here's what shows up: http://pasteboard.co/P3WXWgPk.png

However, the code works if I'm already logged into Rally. Is there anything I'm missing from my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js?apiKey=CorrectAPIKeyHere"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initPage() {
      console.log(gon.project_oid);
      var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("workspace_id", project_id,"true","false");

      console.log($(main_content).width());

      var config = {
          report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.IterationBurndown,
          height: 400,
          iterations: iteration_id
      };
      var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config);
      report.display("burndown_chart");
    }

    rally.addOnLoad(initPage);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are a couple different things contributing to your current bad times.  API Keys are not supported in App SDK 1.x.  They are also not supported by the Analytics1 service which backs that StandardReport component.

So the only way forward is to go back to using LoginKey, which comes with the usual caveats about security, etc.  Did you have a working app with LoginKey?

Comment: I haven't been able to test out LoginKey because of account constraints (I'm in the process of obtaining a read-only account to generate the LoginKey). However, I will update this post once I find out more! (Right now, when I go to the key generation page, the generate button is disabled - I'm assuming it's because I have the wrong account type.)

Answer (score 0):

Good news!  Api Keys are fully supported now in App SDK 2.1 and the StandardReport component so it should be totally possible to do this now.

Some useful links:

Embedding apps externally:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps

The StandardReport component: 
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport